# How to run DynamoDB web service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Have been reading aws guidelines for a while, but still cannot run a dynamoDB webservice. Already have a working codebase, just need to run a webservice and get access keys and endpoint url. The only button amazon shows is Create table, which I do not need as I create them from code.

Comment: Do you mean a local copy of the DynamoDB webservice?

Comment: You get credentials by launching your AWS compute with an appropriate IAM role *and* using an AWS SDK to retrieve and use the credentials. The SDK knows the DynamoDB service endpoint so you don't need to provide that.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for giving a right track to my destination, havent looked there:) but in an online tutorial there is a method: `.withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8000", Regions.US_WEST_2.getName()))` I should call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, the endpoints to access dynamoDB are regional and don't depend on the table name, you can find them here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Second thing, if you create tables and access them from the same application (running on AWS) you should use AWS roles and make sure you give the right permissions to the IAM policy associated with the role, if you're creating the tables from one specific service and accessing them from different services than you need to make sure every service has the right role and, again IAM policy associated to the role, finally if you're accessing them with different users you need to make sure those users have an associeted IAM policy that gives them access.

If you don't want to create a big amount of policies and you don't want to modified them when you create new resources you can use a prefix for the name of your tables such as `app_a_...` and in the policies give access to the right subset of resources using the same prefix for example

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "accessToAppAtables",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "dynamodb:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT_ID>:table/app_a_*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html) document.

Comment: wow, that is actually some info I did not find in getting started guide, thanks! So DynamoDB is enabled by default and the only thing I need to do is to create a role which will have the permission to write to database?

Comment: Have just attached dynamodb full access policy to my aws compute, where do I get access keys to enable my aws compute write to dynamodb?

Comment: If you are going to use a role you don't need access keys, in fact, roles generate and rotates them automatically. So, create a role, attach the policy to that role, and then attach the role to the EC2 instance that's going to be running the code